# Purpose of ～とは in 「あなたにとって仕事とはなんでしょうか」

Tags: grammar

> あなたにとって仕事【しごと】**とは**なんでしょうか

What is the purpose of `とは` above?
Would using `は` alone have been any different?

If `とは` is a grammatical construct, I would appreciate additional examples clarifying its significance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“とは” introduces a definition.

“AとはBである” = “The definition of A is B”

In your example:
“あなたにとって仕事 **とは** なんですか” = “How do you define jobs?” where “What do you work for?” is implied.

“あなたにとって仕事 **は** なんですか” sounds awkward and is interpreted as “あなたの仕事はなんですか” (= “What is your job?”).

Comment: Would using ことは or のは be inappropriate here?

Comment: @IUnknown “仕事{ことは|のは}なんですか”? They sound strange.