# どのような and a particle soup

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I have the following sentence:

> 熊の神**と**はどのようなものか、想像してみたが...

My book translates this as

> I tried to imagine what the Bear God might be like.

I have multiple problems:

1) I think どのような means "what kind of" so would I be correct in saying that a more literal (not better) translation would be " I tried to imagine what kind of thing the bear god is"?

2) What is the purpose of the と after 熊の神?

3) Why is there no と before 想像する? Would it be okay to add one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) It defines the thing being talked about. In this case it is `熊の神`. See some previous answers: [Purpose of ～とは in 「あなたにとって仕事とはなんでしょうか」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19310/purpose-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF-in-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E4%BB%95%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B)

3) I think it would be okay to have a と. I'm not very certain about this one though.

Comment: I don't think you can add a と after か here - with embedded questions, you just use か. You would add と to quote a question (with e.g. ～かと思った).